# How do I change the UIPageViewController from WITHIN one of the UIViewControllers that is part of the UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, and I must be misunderstanding how `UIPageViewController` works.

I have 5 setup screens (separate view controllers that are loaded into the `UIPageViewController`) that I can swipe right + left to see.

**BUT! I want to be able to programmatically show the next view controller in line after they dismiss an alert on one of those view controllers.**

**And so far, the only solution that I've found that gets close, is this solution here ( https://github.com/jeffaburt/UIPageViewController-Post ) that allows a "next" button, but the button isn't on the view controller that's showing, it's on the root view controller that holds the `UIPageViewController`.**

I have the `UIPageViewController` set up to show 5 different view controllers, with this code.

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newColoredViewController("setup1"),
            self.newColoredViewController("setup2"),
            self.newColoredViewController("setup3"),
            self.newColoredViewController("setup4"),
            self.newColoredViewController("setup5")]
}()
```

Then the `newColoredViewController` function does this:

```
private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(color)")
}
```

and here's my `viewDidLoad`:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self



    if let SetupViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([SetupViewController],
                           direction: .Forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }


}
```

I must be missing some fundamental understanding, because I've tried so many different ways to change the page programmatically, and nothing happens.

**I've tried doing this, but it does nothing:**

```
setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[3]],
                           direction: .Forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
```

**I've tried doing this, but it does nothing:**

```
func scrollToNextViewController() {
    if let visibleViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let nextViewController = pageViewController(self,
                                                    viewControllerAfterViewController: visibleViewController) {
        scrollToViewController(nextViewController)
    }
}
```

Please point me in the right direction!! I can research all day and usually can figure it out thanks to previous stackoverflow questions that are already answered, but here I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out an easier way to do it within the structure I'd already set up. In the UIPageViewController, added this function:

```
func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int)
{
   // let nextWalkthroughVC = newColoredViewController("setup4")
    let nextWalkthroughVC = orderedViewControllers[index]
        setViewControllers([nextWalkthroughVC], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and then in one of the setup View Controllers I created a button action that ran this code:

```
@IBAction func yeaaa(sender: AnyObject) {
              let parent = self.parentViewController as! SetupViewController

    parent.nextPageWithIndex(3)
}
```

(where "SetupViewController" is the UIPageViewController)

YEEHAWWWW that was driving me nuts.

Here's the video that gave me the idea of "self.parentViewController as! SetupViewController" and the "nextPageWithIndex" code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CSBxX5VXA

Answer (score 0):

I guess in `newColoredViewController` you create the instances of the view controllers that are to be shown by the `pageViewController`.

There you shoud pass into a reference to the showing view controller. Something like
`newSetupViewConroller.setNextDelegate(self)`.

Define a protocol `NextDelegate` that has a method `performNext`

That should be the type of the parameter (and the correlating instance variable) of `setNextDelegate`. 
(Alternatively to a setter method you can of course declare some property of type `NextDelegate`)

Your presenting view controller should conform to this protocol and implement the `performNext` method.

When you did that then you have access to the presenting view controller (as an object that conforms to the protocol) and you can call its method `performNext`.

Within the method `performNext` you are in your presenting view controller and have access to the `pageViewController` and go from there.

(There are easier ways of doing this, but I think this is a proper one. That is what protocols are made for.)

Comment: Ack! I barely understand how to implement what you just explained.

So, I should change the function 
`private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(color)")
}`

and try to pass in a variable? When you say "pass into a reference to the showing view controller, how do I do that?

Comment: You said that there were easier ways of doing this -- could you shed any light on those? I'm all for proper ways of doing things but honestly I don't think I could implement what you explained because I'm not that level of a coder yet!!

Comment: Yes, don't return the instance directly but hold it in some local variable for a moment and pass in the presenting view controller. 

But my advise is not to declare the parameter as object of the class of the presenting view controller but to use a protocol in between. Coupling of classes in both ways works fine but is not really good style.

Comment: You could omit the protocol. Then you have a class A "knowing" class B. That is ok so far. But you would have to make class B "knowing" class A too. That is a cyclic depencency which should be avoided. Better is declaring a protocol C and making A implementing/conforming to the protocol. Doing so, B only needs to "know" the protocol C. That serves the purpose but avoids a cyclic dependency. (This is an example of the delegation pattern which is commonly used in iOS anyway.)

Comment: Experienced coders may find lamda expressions more convenient. They are certainly less coding work and serve the same purpose of de-coupling the two classes but as you say you are not that much of a coder, the delegation pattern is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**First, we need to access parent class as PageViewController**

Swift 5 :

```
   if let controller = self.parent as? yourPageViewController             
          controller.goToNextPage()
   }
```

**PageViewController Extension can be used like that**

```
extension UIPageViewController {

    func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
        guard let nextViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) else { return }
        setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

    func goToPreviousPage(animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
        guard let previousViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController) else { return }
        setViewControllers([previousViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
}
```