# Change specific page UiPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller

I have a Page view controller (see below), what i want to achieve is to go to the FirstVC from ThirdVC and only from that!! with a function or a button, can anyone help me?

Here you can see the code of my PageVC

```
import UIKit

class PageVC: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    lazy var VCArr: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.VCInstance(name: "FirstVC"), self.VCInstance(name: "SecondVC"), self.VCInstance(name: "ThirdVC")]
          }()

    private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController  {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        if let firstVC = VCArr.first {
            setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if view is UIScrollView {
                view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            } else if view is UIPageControl {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else{
            return VCArr.last
        }

        guard VCArr.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return VCArr[previousIndex]
    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        guard nextIndex < VCArr.count else{
            return VCArr.first
        }

        guard VCArr.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return VCArr[nextIndex]
    }

     public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return VCArr.count
    }


     public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: firstViewController) else{
            return 0
        }
        return firstViewControllerIndex
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution here:

[How do I change the UIPageViewController from WITHIN one of the UIViewControllers that is part of the UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427327/how-do-i-change-the-uipageviewcontroller-from-within-one-of-the-uiviewcontroller)

```
Simply i added this function to PageVC:
 func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int)
    {

        let nextWalkthroughVC = VCArr[index]
        setViewControllers([nextWalkthroughVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Then in the ThirdVC view controller i added in my function:

```
let parent = self.parent as! PageVC

        parent.nextPageWithIndex(index: 0)
```

Where 0 is the index of the view controller that i want to show

And works perfectly!